# Rename Remote/Local File Then Upload (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a scenario (though been searching, have not found any lead yet) wherein user attempts to upload, but before clicking upload, user renames the filename/deletes the file.

How do I capture this in code (PHP) once user clicks upload button?

Please help. Thanks.

Sample codes would be very well appreciated. Concepts would also do.

Thanks.

Note: I am using CodeIgniter Framework

Comment: I've tried file_exist but just realized that it works only on the server. I'm still thinking and researching of other work arounds.

Comment: That sounds like kind of a rare scenario to try to account for. If your user does that, it's completely their fault. Why would they be doing that anyway?

Comment: Yes you are right, but the concern would be "how to capture the error" and display the correct error message. Or even just maintaning the looks of you page rather than showing those cryptic messages client won't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't capture the delete/rename events in PHP. Your upload handling script is fired up only **AFTER** the upload completes (regardless of success/failure). At most you can check for failure, e.g.

```
if ($_FILES['yourfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Hey, the upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['yourfile']['error']);
}
```

The codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: It has been a year or so. But let me share a way on handling this kind of scenario though rare.
In upload.php (CI library), I tweaked a portion and added a condition. If the file size of the file goes less than what is expected (ex. less than 8bytes/becomes 0byte), then I considered it an upload error. Why? Because files, except probably .txt, must contain header info/metadata even when empty (no image, no contents)....(cont.)

Comment: ......(cont) If the file size went less or 0bytes, then you can expect that something went wrong at the client side during upload. Also, you don't want a 0 byte file uploaded in your server..... We'll, quite a crude way though.
You got my acceptance point Marc. Apologies if it took a year to do so. I rarely visit this place this year :|